# Drawing freehand in QGIS?

Tags: qgis

Besides the beePen plugin is there a way of creating freehand polygons and lines in QGIS 3.8.1?

I'm trying to draw freehand lines,etc. over a raster image and would prefer not to have to continuously click to create a vertex.

Answer (score 2):

Except for BeePen, there are two plugins that I'm aware of, FreeHand Editing and possibly CADtools. If you want to use them in QGIS 3.x you can easily check the code according to [this guide](https://www.opengis.ch/2018/04/13/porting-qgis-plugins-to-api-v3-strategy-and-tools/) and then port the plugin to API V3 using:

```
pip install qgis2to3
qgis2to3 -w /path/to/your/plugin
```